# How to disable ellipsis autocorrect on macOS?

Tags: keyboard, macos, autocorrect

Every time i write `...` in a text editor like TextEdit or Coda, Lion has started replacing it with a single Ellipse character, which doesn't encode to HTML. This started after I upgraded to Lion and happens across multiple programs. This persists in the latest Big Sur betas.

Any idea how to stop it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Go to System Preferences, select `Language & Text`, then the `Text` tab, and deselect the box for that option.
[image]

Or you can disable the feature completely by deselecting the box at the top.

Comment: Thanks. I have done this and it works in all apps except Evernote. Evernote has no pref for this in the Preferences. Any idea of how to fix it? Thanks for entertaining this random aside.

Comment: @Yar Sorry, I don't know. You could ask your own question specifically for Evernote and see if someone else does.

Comment: Certain apps seem to not respect the system "substitution" settings. In Adium, for instance, turn off ellipsis by opening a chat window, right-clicking in the textbox (where you type a message), then select `Substitutions` and de-select `Smart Dashes`. I could not find this setting in the actual `Adium->Preferences` dialog. A similar sequence might work for other apps with a composition field. See also [this other answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/157527/97853).

Answer (score 22):

In Mavericks at least, this seems to be controlled by the "Use smart quotes and dashes" feature found in System Preferences → Keyboard → Text. Uncheck the box, and the behavior goes away, even in Evernote.

[image: System Preferences → Keyboard → Text → Use smart quotes and dashes]

Comment: I'm using TextEdit on 10.9.2, and I'm finding that I have to restart TextEdit for this change in System Preferences to take effect.

Comment: If you like smart quotes, but still don't want to replace the ellipsis, you need Luke's answer.

Comment: You may have to disable this in specific applications as well. 
 (E.g., Mac Mail:  `Mail/Edit/Substitutions/Smart Dashes` in Mac Mojave 10.14.6)

Answer (score 10):

If "Smart Quotes" is active in Keyboard Settings but you don't want smart ellipses, Edit menu in most applications on OS X Yosemite, unchecking "Smart Dashes" found in Edit -> Substitutions -> Show Substitutions stops autocorrect of three periods to ellipsis.[image]

Comment: Resolved within Textedit or system wide?

Comment: See hoc_age's comment in the "hooked" answer - to get to this menu, you sometimes have to right-click on the input fields of the program that is suffering this issue. That is, the "Substitutions" menu item isn't in the Menu Bar, and only can be "found" by right-clicking on *input fields*. Bah.

Comment: This works for me in Apple Mail (El Capitan).

Answer (score 9):

On older OS X, you could see and disable this autocorrection, but now the interface is similar but you have to ***add this entry to manage it.***

[image: 2020 screenshot of how ellipsis text replacement would appear in macOS]

Make three periods generate three periods. Also look for app settings like smart quotes and dashes. Those can really be bad when writing code.

The official term for this is “Create text replacements” and you have to add the ones you prefer like I have shown...

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/replace-text-punctuation-documents-mac-mh35735/mac

Comment: Interesting that replacement does not even appear in KeyNote's preferences, but [turning off  "use smart quotes and dashes"  does stop KeyNote from doing the replacement](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/401163/how-can-i-stop-macos-from-converting-three-dots-to-a-single-threedot-chara#comment556043_401163). I'll go ahead now and look for a system-wide Keyboard preference pane to see what's there (I have 10.15.6)

Comment: I don't see a ... there either, in fact no suggested replacements at all are explicitly listed at all, except "omw" https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf2qq.png but presumably turning off "use smart quotes and dashes" should do the same thing here.

Comment: You have to add it by clicking the plus in the bottom left. This is your place to override the system defaults. @uhoh  I’ve edited in the applicable help article. It’s hard to search Apple when you don’t know the term to search. (And I didn’t know the term until you asked me...)

Comment: I don't understand exactly what to add in order for it to leave it alone and not replace it. Should I just put the same three separate dots on both sides, a sort of null-replace?

Comment: Add three periods on the left, then add three on the right @uhoh - this hijacks the other option of substituting the Unicode three dots character.

Comment: you mean three periods on the left and *three periods* identically on the right also, correct? The documentation says nothing about this.

Comment: Totally, I have tested this. Yes you “replace” the text with the exact same text. I’ll bold what I mentioned above ***override the system defaults***

Comment: Interestingly [or not, depending on your perspective;) because I never have 'smart quotes' set yet use an ellipsis frequently, I had to actually **add** it to text replacements.

Comment: When `/Mail/Edit/Smart Dashes` is selected on my Mac Mojave 10.14.6, they seem to operate and replace a '...' with a '…' character before `System Preferences/Keyboard/Text` replacement can apply.

Answer (score 4):

It is a system-wide feature for text input, I guess it comes for free in Cocoa, maybe someone knows better.

To disable it right click in a text box (or open the *Edit* menu) and go to *Substitutions* and disable *Smart Dashes* (the dashes features also transforms `--` to an en dash —.) You can also enable the *Substitutions* window from there if you need to toggle settings on a frequent basis.

The setting seems to be on a per document (or text box?) basis

[image: Screen shot of context menu in TextEdit]

Comment: Thanks! To double check, this works for Keynote, and it's on a per-document basis?

Comment: It works in Keynote but interestingly it’s an app-wide setting. In TextEdit it is per document. I’m not 100% sure about the scope of the setting (document, app, system) to be honest.

Comment: okay thanks, one more piece of the puzzle... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> immediately after a text substitution to undo it.