# How can I stop macOS from converting three dots "..." to a single threedot character "…"?

Tags: keynote, textedit, autocorrect

**note:** the first set of three dots in the title is definitely three separate dots, and the second is one character when I select it during editing. However viewing the posted in Safari *both* select as a single character.

---

I sometimes write explicitly three periods in a row "..." in a text field <s>in TextEdit or</s> in Keynote when discussing a bit of code or script, (e.g. `X[..., 1]` in Python puts a 1 in the last axis of a multidimensional array) and either Keynote or macOS says "Oh, I'm going to change what you typed to something you probably wanted instead" and converts it to `X[…, 1]`

I would like my laptop to stop doing that, in Keynote and basically *anywhere!*

How can I do this?

macOS 10.15.6

"Bonus points" for sharing how to stop it from putting periods at the ends of anything it thinks might be a sentence.

---

I have found that on a case-by-case basis I can stop and undo what is already done, but I just want to suppress this behavior from the beginning.

[image: give me back what I typed to begin with please! Converting the trippledot character back to three dots]